# how to navigate using a component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I wish to navigate to a different screen using a component. I know that I can simply pass a prop for onPress in TouchableOpacity and add `props.navigation.navigate("")` every time I use that component. But since I'm using this component multiple times and the destination screen is the same all the times, I wish to find a way to do this: (this always gives me this error)

[image]

```
<TouchableHighlight
  underlayColor="#F0F3F4"
  style={style.option}
  onPress={() =>
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Change Password")
  }
>
  <Text style={style.optionText}>Other Links</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This is a part of my code from the Header.js component.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What error you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to design a functional component is to use hooks.

In this case you need to use the hook useNavigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

<TouchableHighlight
  underlayColor="#F0F3F4"
  style={style.option}
  onPress={() =>
    navigation.navigate("Change Password")
  }
>
  <Text style={style.optionText}>Other Links</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a router in your react app to navigate to different routes and links

a basic example here:
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic